# a simple multithreaded alarm clock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I am currently studying the multithreaded programming and I am having a hard time mastering shared resources between threads.

I have two shared resources, `time` and `alarm`

I have three threads, one keeps updating `time` every second, one monitors `time` against `alarm` and finally one changes `time` and `alarm` at user request.

this is to be done using mutual exclusion semaphore, I have a simple setup described below:

1. `Main` thread, program begins here, hosts `time` and `alarm` common variables and instantiates sub threads.
2. `Tick` sub-thread, sleeps every 1000ms, then modifies `Mother` thread's `time` variable
3. `UserInput` sub-thread, is blocked until a user input is caught, and modifies either `time` or `alarm` in `Main` thread.
4. `Alarm` sub-thread, sleeps every 1000ms, goes off when `alarm` == `time`

The `Main` thread keeps a mutex for each resource so only one thread can access it at a time.

Is such design reasonable or am I just over complicating things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first comment would be on the language you use, which may be an indication of some misunderstanding on your part. A thread doesn't **own** any variables; this may mean that you have declared several custom subclasses of `Thread`. If that is so, this would not be an advisable approach. Note that `Thread` is just the name of a class, it is not the actual thread—exactly the same way as `File` is not a file. You haven't posted any code so I must resort to guesswork, but if what I describe is true then you should redesign. Use plain classes (that don't subclass anything) and instantiate `Thread` with a `Runnable`.

Second, it is not very clear what you imply by "mutex" as this is not a term defined by the Java Language Specification. If you mean something from the `java.util.concurrent` package, such as `Semaphore`, this would be overkill; if you mean just plain Java `Object` instances that you use as locks, that would be a simple and straightforward approach. Note, however, that you don't really need any locking at all: `volatile` variables would be enough, or, at most, `AtomicLong`s (or whatever type you use) for the two timestamp values, so you can update them atomically.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Mutex is a custom binary Semaphore package already provided by my professor, it does exactly like what it sounds. and Yes all the threads are custom classes extended from `Thread` class. for the sub threads, are you saying I should create anonymous Runnable classes instead? If I were to use Runnable anonymous objects, how can I pass shared resource from the main object with the whole locking mechanism?

Comment: The anonymous class instance can reach all the properties of the object owning the method where it is created, as well as all `final` local variables in scope. That should be enough to pass everything necessary.

Comment: BTW I truly wonder why you would need a whole custom binary Semaphore package to reimplement a built-in Java feature.

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for! An anonymous runnable made things a million times simpler! As for the custom Semaphore, I believe it's because it is going to be an embeded program, and the professor wants to avoid possibly legal issues with Oracle. not too sure about the exactly reason, I just know that we had to use his package.

Comment: A note to an interested student: if this is an embedded system you are designing, you should probably be thrifty on system resources, in this case threads. Your main thread doesn't do anything useful and it is questionable whether you need a separate thread to handle alarms. Also, the ticking thread, is it is designed, will result in clock drift since it doesn't synchronize with the system clock. If you made a scheme where you check the system clock periodically, you could also reuse that same thread to handle alarms (unless that handling is time-expensive, but I doubt it).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can simply use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Here is a class with a method that sets up a ScheduledExecutorService to beep every ten seconds for an hour:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
class BeeperControl {
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void beepForAnHour() {
    final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
        };
    final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = 
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
        }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
}
```